# Как избавиться от deadlock при использовании mutex?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

В первом потоке так:

```
mutex1.lock();
mutex2.lock();
```

Во втором так:

```
mutex2.lock();
mutex1.lock();
```

Проблема в том, что эти мьютексы находятся в разных классах, скажем `Parent` и `Child`, они вызывают методы друг друга, но ничего не знают о внутреннем устройстве друг друга (но если надо, их можно научить, но только как?). Мьютексы защищают какие-то внутренние данные соответствующих классов.

Это происходит при вложенных вызовах:

Callstack - thread 1

```
10. mutex2.lock();
 9. child.method2();
 8. mutex1.lock();
 7. parent.method1();
....
```

Callstack - thread 2

```
10. mutex1.lock(); 
 9. parent.anotherMethod();
 8. mutex2.lock();
 7. child.someMethod();
....
```

Может есть какой-то паттерн для такой проблемы.

Comment: Как бы это не звучало, но единственный способ избежать дедлоков это не использовать мьютексы. И, как показывает практика, в очень большом количестве случаев их можно избежать.

Answer (score 11):

Чтобы избавиться от дедлоков, можно использовать функцию `std::lock`. Она принимает несколько мьютексов, и лочит их с помощью специального алгоритма который позволяет избежать дедлоков.

Применять ее следует таким образом:

```
std::lock(mutex1, mutex2);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard1(mutex1, std::adopt_lock);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard2(mutex2, std::adopt_lock);
```

Или наоборот, сначала создать `lock_guard`, а потом залочить:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard1(mutex1, std::defer_lock);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard2(mutex2, std::defer_lock);
std::lock(mutex1, mutex2);
```

Comment: Насколько я понял, проблема у ТС состоит в том, что классы имеют по одному мьютексу и не знают друг о друге. То в данном случае по идее не поможет.

Comment: Но техника хорошая, не знал о ней. +1.

Comment: Я тоже не знал. А [вот описание](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/lock/?kw=lock) / Интересно, какие дополнительные задержки и в каких ситуациях?

Answer (score 7):

**Обновление:**
В вашем случае, когда у каждого класса свой мьютекс, и проблема лишь в порядке вызовов, я бы **очень не рекомендовал** вызывать чужой код под блокировкой. Именно потому, что этот код имеет полное право залочить какой-то другой мьютекс. Вызов чужого кода под залоченным мьютексом — практически всегда опасность deadlock'а.

Попробуйте реорганизовать код так, чтобы он выглядел следующим образом:

```
void obj1.method1()
{
    {
        std::lock_guard g1(mutex1);
        // работаем с данными/запоминаем их
    }
    // только здесь мы имеем право вызвать объект, который мы не контролируем
    obj2.method2();
}
```

---

Вы не можете выбраться из этой ситуации. Классы, использующие общие мьютексы, *должны* кооперироваться.

Часто проблема решается таким образом: мьютексы перенумеровываются, и если код хочет взять несколько мьютексов, он обязан брать их в порядке возрастания номеров.

С другой стороны, можно уменьшить гранулярность блокировки, и использовать *один* мьютекс вместо обоих (если это допустимо в рамках вашей задачи).

Также, вы можете попытаться избежать проблемы двойного мьютекса тем, что разделите работу с блокируемыми объектами на части/сущности: сначала залочите один мьютекс и извлечёте нужные данные, затем отпустите этот мьютекс и залочите другой, используя при работе со вторым объектом локально сохранённые данные.

Ещё один подход, завоёвывающий популярность — избавиться по возможности от разделяемых данных, и работать как можно больше с локальными данными.

---

Резюме: общего решения не существует. Выкручивайтесь.

Comment: Еще забыл сказать, что мьютексы у меня рекурсивные. И почти везде используется `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: @zenden2k: подправил код в примере

Comment: У меня 2 класса `Parent` и `Child`. Может, мне стоит внутри `Child` сначала лочить мьютекс Parent-a? типо `parent.mutex.lock();this->mutex.lock();` Правда это внесет дополнительные задержки.

Comment: @zenden2k: Не стоит, это нарушит инкапсуляцию. А отпустить мьютекс во время вызова другого класса точно не покатит? Это обычно правильный дизайн.

Answer (score 7):

Вам уже ответили очень много полезного, хотелось бы добавить еще пару моментов :

- в случае, когда работа с данными постороена таким образом, что никак
  не избежать захватов двух мьютексов, советуют **предопределить
  очередность захвата** этих мьютексов, и во всех потоках
  придерживаться этой очередности;
- в тех случаях, когда архитектура не позволяет предопределить
  очередность захвата мьютексов, можно использовать std::try_lock(),
  которая в случае невозможности захвата мьютекса, возвращает
  управление. Таким образом, если поток захватил первый мьютекс, но не
  может захватить второй, - он может освободить первый, выполнить
  какую-то другую рутинную работу (вместо того, чтобы висеть на одном
  из мьютексов), и вернуться к попытке захвата этих мьютексов вновь.